# How to include gradle multi-project repository as git submodule in another gradle project

Tags: java, git, gradle, git-submodules

I'm trying to import a Gradle multi-project repository into another Gradle project as a git submodule.

This is the structure of the multi-project repo:

```
MyLibrary
- lib-api
  - api-config
  - api-repository
- lib-impl
  - impl-config
  - impl-repository
```

Within the Gradle project `MyLibrary`, there are several modules that depend on other modules within that project. For example, `lib-api:api-repository` has the following dependency:

```
implementation project(':lib-api:api-config')
```

*(the modules under `lib-impl` also include their respective api as a dependency)*

So far everything is ok, I can build, run and test the projects under `lib-impl`.

### Now I try to import the project into another project

I use `git submodule add` to add `MyLibrary` to `MyProject`. This is now the structure:

```
MyProject
- MyLibrary
  - lib-api
    - api-config
    - api-repository
  - lib-impl
    - impl-config
    - impl-repository
- api
- impl
```

In order to be able to use the modules under `MyLibrary`, I edit the `settings.gradle` file in `MyProject` to look something like this:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyProject'
include 'api'
include 'impl'
include 'mylibrary'
include 'mylibrary:lib-api'
include 'mylibrary:lib-impl'
include 'mylibrary:lib-api:api-config'
include 'mylibrary:lib-api:api-repository'
include 'mylibrary:lib-impl:impl-config'
include 'mylibrary:lib-impl:impl-repository'
```

## The problem

Now that the modules under `MyLibrary` belong to the root project `MyProject`, all the internal dependencies within `MyLibrary` need to be prefixed with `:mylibrary`. But this is only the case if `MyLibrary` is currently a submodule of another project.

In order to build `MyProject`, I need to change the dependencies inside `MyLibrary` from this:

```
implementation project(':lib-api:api-config')
implementation project(':lib-api:api-repository')
```

to this:

```
implementation project(':mylibrary:lib-api:api-config')
implementation project(':mylibrary:lib-api:api-repository')
```

However, `:mylibrary` needs to NOT be present for `MyLibrary` to compile successfully by itself (i.e. if `MyLibrary` is the root project). But this change IS required for `MyLibrary` to work as a submodule.

This used to not be a big problem as I could always pull the submodule `MyLibrary` and edit the necessary `build.gradle` files. However, I have now started trying to set up continuous integration and I get errors about those imports being invalid inside `MyLibrary` whenever I try to build `MyProject` as CI will always get the code directly from the git repo.

I feel like if the following statement was valid, it could fix my problem:

```
implementation project(':mylibrary:lib-api:api-config').ifNotPresent(':lib-api:api-config')
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a brilliant revelation, I realized that java code was allowed inside of the `build.gradle` file so naturally I did this:

```
dependencies {
    if (rootProject.getName().equals("MyLibrary")) {
        implementation project(':lib-api:api-config')
    } else {
        implementation project(':mylibrary:lib-api:api-config')
    }
}
```

And it works!