# Gradle module dependencies within a Git submodule

Tags: gradle, module, dependencies, git-submodules

I'm dealing with an increasingly convoluted Gradle project and I'm having some trouble with the project dependency interactions of the project's submodules. Here's a quick visualization of the project structure:

```
MyApp
 - settings.gradle
 - app_module_1
     - build.gradle
 - app_module_2
     - build.gradle
 - *MyLibrary*
    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
    - library_module_1
       - build.gradle
    - library_module_2
       - build.gradle
```

In my project 'MyApp,' I have two modules (app_module_1 and app_module_2). I also have a Git submodule which references another Gradle project (MyLibrary) which has its own set of modules. The root MyLibrary project has its own sources as well.

I'm trying to figure out how I should be referencing module project dependencies within my library. For instance, library_module_1 is dependent on the parent project (MyLibrary). Within the library project itself, I can reference this within library_module_1's build.gradle like so:

`implementation project(':')`

Unfortunately, when adding MyLibrary as a git submodule in MyApp, these project references no longer work. I can fix this by changing the project dependency within the library submodule as follows:

`implementation project(':MyLibrary')`

This doesn't work when building the standalone MyLibrary project though. I'm stuck in a catch-22 and I'm not really sure how to set up these dependencies to satisfy both MyApp and MyLibrary. Is it possible to reference modules relative to a certain module's path?

Thanks, I appreciate any advice I can get!

Comment: This solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858898/how-to-include-gradle-multi-project-repository-as-git-submodule-in-another-gradl

It seems like an unpleasant way to deal with the issue though. I'm assuming I would run into the same issue if I included the library two layers deep.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like breakthroughs always happen as soon as you ask for help.

For anyone in a situation like this in the future, you can easily reference your parent's path as follows:

`implementation project(parent.path)`

Aesthetically pleasing solution and works regardless of the relative hierarchy of modules.

Cheers!